# iOS 10 GM embedded UITableView and UICollectionView contentSize wrong and scroll indicators not showing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift3, ios10

My UI has a view controller with two embedded views, like so:

```
-----------------
|        |      |
|  List  | Grid |
|        |      |
-----------------
```

The list view has a `UITableView` and the grid has a `UICollectionView`. Both were working fine in iOS 9.

In iOS 10, I have two problems:

- Both views scroll way past their content. The content size is too large.
- Neither is showing a scroll indicator.

Anyone else encountered these issues with scroll views in embedded view controllers and has any idea how to work around it?

Note: I feel that this may be related to the old (new) autoresizing/springs and struts system, and strange behaviour where views added as custom objects in the Storyboard are resized to 1000x1000.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Updated to ios10 and now my collection view has a content size of 1340.

Comment: You Sir are a legend. I was banging my head about this for a long time. I wonder why it stopped working when using iOS 10 through. Maybe the calls made by apples frameworks are different?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm experiencing every subview of a UITableViewCell being set to 1000x1000 at first load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the `.frame` property of another view (in this case a toolbar) to calculate the tableView's `contentInsets`. That view's frame was queried in `viewDidLoad` (probably before it was set) and returned 1000x1000. I've replaced all queries of the `.frame` property with constraints and it's helped me fix all these iOS 10 sizing issues.

Comment: Yep that fixed it for me. (you should accept your own answer)

Answer (score 0):

Call `layoutIfNeeded` before.
This problem appear with XCode 8. 
I have the same problem in `willDisplayCell`.

Answer (score -1):

This is Xcode8 problem, simply change story board property "Opens In" to "XCode  7.x"and revert back to XCode 7.

Your views will get proper values after reverting back.